$f^{-1}(\varphi)_{x} = \varphi_{f(x)}$ ( Stalk of the inverse image )?
It seems easy question but don't find rigorous argument about it until now. Let $f : X\to Y$ be a continuous map. Then we obtain a functor $f^{-1}$ from the category of presheaves on $Y$ to the category of sheaves on $X$ ; Let $\mathcal{G}$ be a presheaf on $Y$. Then $f^{-1}\mathcal{G}$ is the sheafification of $f^{+}\mathcal{G}$, where $f^{+}\mathcal{G} : U \mapsto \mathrm{colim}_{V \supseteq f(U), V \subseteq Y \mathrm{open}}\mathcal{G}(V).$ We know that $(f^{-1}\mathcal{G})_x = \mathcal{G}_{f(x)}.$
Let $\varphi : \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{G}$ be a morphism of presheaves on $Y$.
Then why $f^{-1}\mathcal{G}$ is functorial? ; i.e., how $f^{-1}(\varphi)$ is defined?
And $f^{-1}(\varphi)_{x} = \varphi_{f(x)}$ ( stalk of $\varphi$ at $f(x)$ )?

So, $f^{-1}\varphi$ is defined by using the universal property of colimits, and the universal property of sheafification.
Firstly,
For any open subset $U\subset X$, and any open subset $f(U)\subset W$, there is a homomorphism: $$\mathcal{F}(W)\rightarrow \mathcal{G}(W)\rightarrow \mathrm{colim}_{V \supseteq f(U), V \subseteq Y \mathrm{open}}\mathcal{G}(V).$$
One can check that all necessary diagrams commute, and hence we have a homormohpism: $$f^+(\mathcal{F})(U)=\mathrm{colim}_{V \supseteq f(U), V \subseteq Y \mathrm{open}}\mathcal{F}(V)\rightarrow \mathrm{colim}_{V \supseteq f(U), V \subseteq Y \mathrm{open}}\mathcal{G}(V)=f^+(\mathcal{G})(U).$$ (Comment by OP: More explicitly, it maps an equivalence class $[(W,s)]  (  s \in \mathcal{F}(W)$ ) to $[(W,\varphi_W(s)]$ ? )
This gives you a uniquely defined presheaf homomorphism: $$f^+(\mathcal{F})\rightarrow f^+(\mathcal{G}).$$ Using the universal property of a sheafification, this uniquely defines a sheaf homomorphism: $$f^{-1}(\mathcal{F})\rightarrow f^{-1}(\mathcal{G})$$
As far as stalks go, you can first try and prove the following result:

If $\psi:\mathcal{F} \rightarrow \mathcal{G}$ is a morphism of presheaves of abelian groups on a topological space $X$, then for any $x\in X$, $\mathcal{F}_x\cong\mathcal{F}^{\#}_x$ and $\mathcal{G}_x\cong\mathcal{G}^{\#}_x$, and additionally $\psi_x$ and $\psi^{\#}_x$ are the 'same' maps (Here $\{\cdot\}^{\#}$ denotes sheafification).

So, it is enough the understand how the homomorphism of stalks are defined on the level presheaves. Now, for any $x\in X$, it not hard to check that $f^+(\mathcal{F})_x\cong \mathcal{F}_{f(x)}$ (this is because there are both colimits of abelian groups indexed by 'essentially' the same system), and a similar result is also true for $\mathcal{G}$. Hence $f^{-1}(\varphi)_x=f^+(\varphi)_x=\varphi_{f(x)}$.
Sketch promised in the comments section: The stalk $$\mathcal{F}_{f(x)}=\mathrm{colim}_{V \supseteq f(x), V \subseteq Y \mathrm{open}}\mathcal{F}(V),$$ and the stalk $$f^+(\mathcal{F})_x=\mathrm{colim}_{U \supseteq x, U \subseteq Y \mathrm{open}}\mathcal{f^+(F)}(U)=\mathrm{colim}_{U \supseteq x, U \subseteq Y \mathrm{open}}(\mathrm{colim}_{V \supseteq f(U), V \subseteq Y \mathrm{open}}\mathcal{F}(V)).$$ This idea is to now trace the diagrams and show that combining these two colimits in the second equality gives you the colimit in the first equality. What the precisely means is, you can construct a map: $$f^+(\mathcal{F})_x\rightarrow \mathcal{F}_{f(x)}$$ and show that it is an isomorphism (using the two directed systems).
(Comment by OP: More explicitly, it maps $[(U, [(W,s)])] \mapsto [(W,s)]$ with inverse $[(U,s)] \mapsto [(f^{-1}(U),[(U,s)])]$ ) .

Thanks ! Why $f^{+}(\varphi)x = \varphi{f(x)}$? Perhaps, can you explain that by more elementwise argument?  (  $\divideontimes$ Let $ i : f^{+}(\mathcal{F}) \to f^{-1}(\mathcal{F})$, $ j : f^{+}(\mathcal{G}) \to f^{-1}(\mathcal{G})$ be the sheafification morphisms. Then as you stated ( more precisely ), $f^{-1}(\varphi)_x =  j_x \circ f^{+}(\varphi)_x \circ (i_x)^{-1} $. Why $j_x \circ f^{+}(\varphi)x \circ (i_x)^{-1}  = \varphi{f(x)}$ ) ?

O.K. I will correct my additional question. What will be the explicit form of the isomorphism $f^{+}(\mathcal{F})x \cong \mathcal{F}{f(x)}$? I think it is key point of the elementwise proof.  Can you give me a hint? : )

I shall edit my answer to give you a sketch.

O.K. Thank you. Let's keep going~

O.K. Thanks. Can I ask more? A point that makes me stuck is, how can we send $[(U ,[(W,s)])] \in f^{+}(\mathcal{F})x$ to an element of $\mathcal{F}{f(x)}$, the colimit in the first equality ? Just $[(U ,[(W,s)])] \mapsto [(W,s)]$? And, how can we send $[(U,s)] \in \mathcal{F}_{f(x)}$ to an element of $f^{+}(\mathcal{F})_x$ ( construction of the inverse map ) ? Just $[(U,s)] \mapsto [(f^{-1}(U), [(U,s)])] $? I could show these are mutually inverse and could show that $f^{+}(\varphi)x = \varphi{f(x)}$ up to such isomorphisms. How do you think about that ?

Yes to your first question. For the second one, sure you can construct the inverse, but I would instead show that that one satisfies the universal property of the other. That implies uniqueness

Can you explain your final comment ( satisfaction of the universal property , implication of uniqueness ) more precisely and in detail ?

Anyway, thanks for answer and patience :)

This is a general property of any limit or colimit. These structures have a universal property. And, if there is any other object which has exactly the same universal property, then it is isomorphic to the former. I feel like it would be helpful to read up a little on these universal properties of different structures because it defines them uniquely!

O.K. I will  do it. Thanks  !
